# Spark : Open a database session in some node, broadcast it, retrieve it in another node... The session still works?

Tags: database, networking, cassandra, apache-spark

Suppose we have a spark cluster of multiple nodes. In the driver program, I open a cassandra session (Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(...).build().connect(keyspace)). What happens if I pass this session in a Broadcast variable and retrieve it in another node ? Is this session still usable ? Is a database session (once opened) tied to the machine that opened it ?

It's a bit difficult to try as I don't have a cluster of multiple nodes...

Comment: i think this link will answer your question well http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Which-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-connection-to-an-external-database-per-task-in-Spark-Streaming-td8937.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you are trying to share a session you will need to re-establish it on other nodes (It is not serializable). But if you would like to pool sessions on a particular node you can use the Spark Cassandra Connector.

The Spark Cassandra Connector has an object CassandraConnector(SparkConf) which will pool sessions and makes it easy to share a C* connection between tasks on the same machine.

For example

```
rdd.map( item => CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo ( session => ... ) )
```

Will only utilize 1 C* cluster connection per executor JVM.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md

Comment: C* = Cassandra, Basically you get 1 java driver Cluster object per Executor JVM